# How to detect #includes of nonexistant files in gcc

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

I am using Xcode's modified gcc, and I notice that sometimes when I include a file that doesn't exist, it just silently skips it.  How can I get it to give me a warning?

Comment: Could you post the specific example—the compiler invocation and source file—instead of a paraphrase? Are you sure the #include is being processed, and that there is no file with that name in the include path?

Answer (score 1):

It is likly that the build system, i.e. the xcode builder isn't re-compiling certain source files and so you don't get an error. It's hard to say why. We use Scons for our cross platform builds.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug.  If so, then fixing it might be the best way.

edit: I forgot, Xcode is not open.  Never mind.

Comment: gcc is GPL - if they modified and distributed it the source must be available

Comment: Good point, I guess it's just the IDE that's proprietary? - Are you sure they didn't get around this with the GPL "Linking Exception"?  http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/xcodetools2.2.html

Comment: The links on the page you linked to that refer to "linking exception" don't work.  But in any case, the GPL is very clear, if you distribute modified GPL'd code, you must provide the source to your licensees - no exceptions.

Comment: Xcode's (3.1.3) gcc (4.2) open source is at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5493/ but I don't think that gcc is the issue here.  Until we see what the OP is actually doing this is shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I find it very hard to believe that any version of gcc will not produce an error message if a #include fails, if that is what you are asking about. Have you tried building the code from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I haven't been able to duplicate the problem with a smaller project.  I am/was also getting internal linker graph errors.  Something was seriously messed up in the project or Xcode.

Whatever the issue, using Xcode 3.0 has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

That'ŝ normally something that belongs in the configure script. It checks for some headers and chooses the ones best fitted.